# Deep Linking expo

Tags: expo, expo-linking

I'm trying to test config for deep links, in expo documentation I found next line
`Development in Expo Go: exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/path/into/app?hello=world`, but as soon as I try to run `npx uri-scheme open exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/path/into/app?hello=world --ios` I have an error `no matches found: exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/path/into/app?hello=world`, as soon as I remove query string it works.
Is there any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Didn't find any answers in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found escaping `?` character solves this issue.

```
# Add `\` before `?`
# Replace `127.0.0.1:19000` with your host.

npx uri-scheme open exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/path/into/app\?hello=world --ios
```

This works on iOS simulator only. No luck with Expo Go app.